# How to use classes to create rectangles

Tags: c++, class

I need to create a program that uses a class to create three triangles from user input, including the following specifications:

1. The private data shall consist of 4 members:
   length
   width
   area
   perimeter
2. Have 1 constructor with the following parameters: length and width.
3. Have 2 mutators:
   setLength  to set/modify the length
   and setWidth to set/modify the width.
4. Have 5 accessors:
   getLength to return the length

   getWidth to return the width

   getPerimeter to return the perimeter

   getArea to return the area

   printObjet to print the representation of the rectangle (using the same 
   output criteria of the previous incarnations)

For extra credit Store 10 rectangle objects you created in a vector and sequence through the vector to print out the 10 rectangle objects. Once I get how to do the main assignment I believe I can do this on my own, though extra help wouldn't go amiss.

After editing with the changes from DimChtz the code is below.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

// Rectangle class declaration.
class Rectangle
{
   private:
      double width;
      double length;
      double area;
      double perimeter;


   public:
      void setWidth(double);
      void setLength(double);
      double getWidth();
      double getLength();
      double getArea();
      double getPerimeter();
      void printObjet();
      void calc();
      Rectangle();
};

//beginning class constructor
Rectangle::Rectangle() {
    this->width = 0;
    this->length = 0;
    this->area = 0;
    this->perimeter = 0;
}
// main class constructor
Rectangle::Rectangle(double width, double length)
{   this->width = width;
    this->length = length;
    this->calc();
}
//calc calculates the area and perimeter from width and length.
void Rectangle::calc() {
    this->area = this->width * this->length;
    this->perimeter = 2 * (this->width + this->length); }

// the class functions definition
// setWidth assigns its argument to the private member width.
void Rectangle::setWidth(double width)
{   this->width = width;
    this->calc(); }

// setLength assigns its argument to the private member length.
void Rectangle::setLength(double length)
{   this->length = length;
    this->calc(); }

// getLength returns the value in the private member length.
double Rectangle::getLength()
{   return length; }

// getWidth returns the value in the private member width.
double Rectangle::getWidth()
{   return width; }

// getPerimeter returns parameter of box.
double Rectangle::getPerimeter()
{   return  this->perimeter; }

// getArea returns area of box.
double Rectangle::getArea()
{   return this->area; }

// printObjet prints the data of the rectangle
void Rectangle::printObjet()
{   cout << "  Width = " << getWidth() << endl;
    cout << "  Length = " << getLength() << endl;
    cout << "  Perimeter = " << getPerimeter() << endl;
    cout << "  Area = " << getArea() << endl << endl; }


// the main program
int main()
{
   double width;     // Local variable for width.
   double length;   // Local variable for length.

    // create object using constructor
   Rectangle   box1;
   Rectangle   box2;
   Rectangle   box3;

   // Get the 1st rectangle's width and length from the user.
   cout << "Enter the length of the 1st rectangle: ";
   cin >> length;
   cout << length << endl;
   cout << "Enter the width of the 1st rectangle:  ";
   cin >> width;
   cout << width << endl;


    // Store the width and length of the rectangle in the box1 object.
    box1.setWidth(width);
    box1.setLength(length);

         // Display box1 data.
    cout << "You created a rectangle with the following characteristics:" << endl << endl;
    box1.printObjet();


    // Get the 2nd rectangle's width and length from the user.
    cout << "Enter the length of the 2nd rectangle: ";
    cin >> length;
    cout << length << endl;
    cout << "Enter the width of the 2nd rectangle:  ";
    cin >> width;
    cout << width << endl;

        // Store the width and length of the rectangle in the box1 object.
        box2.setWidth(width);
        box2.setLength(length);

         // Display box2 data.
         cout << "You created a rectangle with the following characteristics:" << endl << endl;
         box2.printObjet();

    // Get the 3rd rectangle's width and length from the user.
    cout << "Enter the length of the 3rd rectangle: ";
    cin >> length;
    cout << length << endl;
    cout << "Enter the width of the 3rd rectangle:  ";
    cin >> width;
    cout << width << endl;

        // Store the width and length of the rectangle in the box1 object.
        box3.setWidth(width);
        box3.setLength(length);

            // Display box3 data.
            cout << "You created a rectangle with the following characteristics:" << endl << endl;
            box3.printObjet();

   return 0;
}
```

The compile errors are now

```
34:1: error: prototype for 'Rectangle::Rectangle(double, double)' does not match any in class 'Rectangle'
 Rectangle::Rectangle(double width, double length)
```

```
5:7: error: candidates are: constexpr Rectangle::Rectangle(Rectangle&&)
 class Rectangle
```

```
5:7: error:                 constexpr Rectangle::Rectangle(const Rectangle&)
```

```
27:1: error:                 Rectangle::Rectangle()
```

Comment: Did you read the compiler errors at least?

Comment: 1) "area and perimeter in the private data not being used" Each time you modify `width` and/or `length` calculate both `area` and `perimeter` and then return them instead of calculating every time. 2) You need `void Rectangle::printObjet()` and then `cout << "  Width = " << ....` 3) You already use this constructor: `Rectangle   box1;`

Comment: @DimChtz that code didn't even compile

Comment: There are just way too many errors compiling. Please check your code, copy the code that does compile, and paste that.

Answer (score 0):

1) Indeed, you don't use `area` and `perimeter`. You should calculate both `area` and `perimeter` each time you modify `width` and/or `length`:

```
Rectangle::Rectangle(double width, double length) {
    this->width = width;
    this->length = length;
    this->calc();
}

void Rectangle::setWidth(double width) {
    this->width = width;
    this->calc();
}

void Rectangle::setLength(double length) {
    this->length = length;
    this->calc();
}

double Rectangle::getPerimeter() { return  this->perimeter; }

double Rectangle::getArea() { return this->area; }
```

and now you need a new private function:

```
void Rectangle::calc() {
    this->area = this->width * this->length;
    this->perimeter = 2 * (this->width + this->length);
}
```

2) You need to change `printObjet` a bit:

```
void printObjet();
// ...
void Rectangle::printObjet() {
    cout << "  Width = " << getWidth() << endl << "  Length = " << getLength() << endl << "  Perimeter = " << getPerimeter() << endl<< "  Area = " << getArea() << endl << endl;
}
```

and then change:

```
cout << box1.printObjet();
```

to:

```
box1.printObjet();
```

3) You need this:

```
Rectangle();

// ...

Rectangle::Rectangle() {
    this->width = 0;
    this->length = 0;
    this->area = 0;
    this->perimeter = 0;
}
```

or simply:

```
Rectangle::Rectangle() : width(0), length(0), area(0), perimeter(0) {  }
```

or even:

```
Rectangle::Rectangle() : Rectangle(0.0, 0.0) {  }
```

Comment: After changing the things you said the only compile errors are in the second rectangle of line 34 "Out-of-line definition of 'Rectangle' does not match any declaration in 'Rectangle'", and the same piece of code doesn't initialize area or perimeter, and is never used.

Comment: In the actual terminal after compiling fails it says "34:1: error: prototype for 'Rectangle::Rectangle(double, double)' does not match any in class 'Rectangle'
 Rectangle::Rectangle(double width, double length)", "5:7: error: candidates are: constexpr Rectangle::Rectangle(Rectangle&&)"